# Firebase Auth & Realtime Database in Xcode: How do I only show data relevant to ONE user not all?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In xcode using both Firebase Auth and Realtime Database, I am trying to create an information based App, where the user login and see information that has already been put into Realtime Database not the whole Database.

How do I link Auth with Database? 
This is what my current database looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWG1j.jpg)

I have two viewControllers, one for login and one when we are loggedIn:

Here is my code for my LoggedIn Page:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoggedInViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var loginlbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tbl: UITableView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var jobList = [JobModel]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let job = jobList[indexPath.row]

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title:job.shipper, message:"Update", preferredStyle:.alert)


        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style:.default){(_) in
               //self.deleteAction(job: job!)
        }
        let updatedAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style:.default){(_) in

            let id = job.id

            let collected = alertController.textFields?[0].text
            let delievered = alertController.textFields?[1].text

           // ref.child("job").setValue("collected")
            //self.update(collected: collected!, delievered: delievered!)

        }

        alertController.addTextField{(textField) in
            textField.text = job.delievered

        }
        alertController.addTextField{(textField) in
            textField.text = job.collected

        }

        alertController.addAction(updatedAction)

        alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func updatedJob(id: String, collected: String, delievered: String){
        let job = [
            "id": id,
            "collected": collected,
            "delivered": delievered]

        ref.child(id).setValue(job)

    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        let job: JobModel

        job = jobList[indexPath.row]

        cell.lblCol.text = job.collection
        cell.lblDel.text = job.delivery
        cell.lblShip.text = job.shipper
        cell.lblCon.text = job.consignee
        cell.lblEmai.text = job.email
        cell.lblRef.text = job.reference
        cell.lblFreight.text = job.freight
        cell.collected.text = job.collected
        cell.delivered.text = job.delievered

        return cell  }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jobList.count
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
FirebaseApp.configure()     }


ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs");

ref.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in

if snapshot.childrenCount>0 {

self.jobList.removeAll()

for jobs in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
    let jobObject = jobs.value as? [String: AnyObject]
    let jobId = jobObject?["id"]
    let jobShipper = jobObject?["shipper"]
    let jobConsignee = jobObject?["consignee"]
    let jobEmail = jobObject?["email"]
    let jobReference = jobObject?["reference"]
    let jobFreight = jobObject?["freight"]
    let jobCollection = jobObject?["collection date"]
    let jobDelivery = jobObject?["delivery date"]
    let jobPod = jobObject?["pod"]
    let jobCollected = jobObject?["collected"]
    let jobDelivered = jobObject?["delivered"]

  let job = JobModel(id: jobId as! String?,
            shipper: jobShipper as! String?,
            consignee: jobConsignee as! String?,
            email: jobEmail as! String?,
            reference: jobReference as! String?,
            freight: jobFreight as! String?,
            collection: jobCollection as! String?,
            delivery: jobDelivery as! String?,
            pod: jobPod as! String?,
            collected: jobCollected as! String?,
            delivered: jobDelivered as! String?)

            self.jobList.append(job)
}
            self.tbl.reloadData()
```

Here is my code for my Login Page:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    static var isAlreadyLaunchedOnce = false

    @IBOutlet weak var txtemail: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtpass: UITextField!


    var isSignin:Bool = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
       }
    }


    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let email = txtemail.text, let passowrd = txtpass.text

        { Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: passowrd) { (user, error) in
                if user != nil {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goto", sender : self)
                }
                else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Username or Password Incorrect", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(okButton)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

So my question is how do I using firebase Login to my database but only see the relevant information for each login not the whole database, because currently I see the whole database in a tableView.

Comment: Access to the data is controlled by rules you define on `Firebase Database`. Check the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart) they have an example of a sample rule for user access.

Comment: Yes, I have read the document and watched the video on it, however still not sure how to use it within my code. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's a code issue, `Firebase` should handle it automatically if your `rules` are configured correctly. They have console where you can setup the rules and test the access based on authenticated or unauthenticated users. I would start there and make sure you get the correct result in the console first.

Comment: Okay currently my firebase rules is set at {
  "rules": {
        ".write": "auth != null",  
        ".read" : "auth != null",
   
      }
    }

Comment: This means if you have a user signed in than you can read and write data on any node of your database.

Comment: Have you considered organizing your data differently? Instead of `jobs` having some reference id like `RE0001`, if the top level key is the `user_id`, with the reference data underneath, you could then restrict the access by the user. using something like `"jobs": {  "$job":{  ".read": "auth !== null && $job == auth.uid" } }`

Answer (score 0):

As Dennin W says you may need a change on your data organization, the way I see it, it's not that complicated, you can save the Auth UID as the id for the job object.

After that You just need to make a query to your DB, something like this:

```
let query = ref.queryEqual(toValue: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, childKey: "id")
```

this line **Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid** retreives the uid of the logged user, and if you change the way you save the **jobs** in your database this query would retrieve the childs that match that id.

Comment: Okay, sorry to sound a little stupid but in my code where should i reference this on my Viewcontroller for my login page or my viewcontroller or my logged in page?

Comment: Keep getting this error: Cannot use instance member 'ref' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Do yo have your code on some repo that I can check?